# mail merge to separate documents with filename based on Merge field

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-access, mail-merge

I'm doing a mail merge from a Access database and I'd like to make many documents from the mail merge, instead of just one. I found a macro that lets me split the merged document after it's made, that but it names the documents 1, 2, 3 etc. I have hundreds of documents I need to make, and renaming them manually is not workable.

Comment: Have you tried this add-in: http://www.gmayor.com/individual_merge_letters.htm

Comment: Please update your question to clarify your requirements. You have not specified what the output file should look like. You don't want numbers... now you say you want the name based on content. What content would this be?

Comment: I want the filename to be based on a field name called posting title in the document. The field is filled from the mail merge process.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [VBA script to separate the document into individual files](http://web.archive.org/web/20141120002201/http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=139).

There are also various [PDF print drivers](http://web.archive.org/save/www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator/manual/save) such as PDF Creator that can either print individual PDF files automatically, or split them into individual files after they are printed to one giant file.

Comment: That code works, but it still outputs the files with numbers as the filenames. I need to be able to name the files based on their content.